# CSS grid: wrap three divs simultaneously

Tags: html, css, grid-layout, css-grid

With CSS grid, how can I style three divs to wrap at the same time when the screen gets smaller ?

That means to go from this:

```
+---------+--+---------+--+---------+
|   div   |  |   div   |  |   div   |
+---------+--+---------+--+---------+
```

to this:

```
+-----+
| div |
+-----+
|     |
+-----+
| div |
+-----+
|     |
+-----+
| div |
+-----+
```

without first going through this intermediary step:

```
+---------+--+---------+
|   div   |  |   div   |
+---------+--+---------+
|         |  |         |
+---------+--+---------+
|   div   |  |         |
+---------+--+---------+
```

With that starter code:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">box 1</div>
  <div class="box">box 2</div>
  <div class="box">box 3</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jLz0aqmj/1/

Comment: why not use flexbox and media query?

Comment: @Gabby_987 for cleanliness of grid-gap compared to negative margins with flexbox or other methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a media query to switch the number of columns from three to one.

[revised jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jLz0aqmj/15/)

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

@media ( max-width: 500px ) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}

.box {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">box 1</div>
  <div class="box">box 2</div>
  <div class="box">box 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Check below fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/jLz0aqmj/8/

```
    <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">box 1</div>
  <div class="box">box 2</div>
  <div class="box">box 3</div>
</div>
```

and css

```
.wrapper{max-width:600px; font-size:0;}
.box{display:inline-block; max-width:200px; width:33%; font-size:13px; background:#ccc;}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {.box{display:block; max-width:100%}}
```